# http response 206 for video in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, sharepoint, httpresponse

I am trying to use the  html tag to play a short clip on my intranet site which runs on the SharePoint Online platform. Here is the code I have tried:

```
<video width="100%" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" src="/sites/pathtosite/SiteAssets/videos/clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

and:

```
<video width="100%" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="/sites/pathtosite/SiteAssets/videos/clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Both versions of these snippets work in chrome and firefox, but no video is shown in IE (v11). When I use the dev tools (press F12) in IE and record network traffic while the page is loading, I see that i get an http response of 206 for the video. It only loads ~12 KB of the file (~5MB total). The initiator column for the request is blank which i thought was weird too.

I understand the 206 is a partial content response, and the browser is supposed to retrieve the file in chunks. It works properly in the other browsers, but IE doesn't request the rest of the file for some reason.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you willing to link the video file so others can test it? Or at least does [**another video**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4) work as expected? (right-click & save, test via intranet)...

Comment: The video you posted does work on our intranet site! What does this mean for my mp4 file? It was converted from .mov to .mp4 (H.264) using VLC (file->convert).

Comment: VC.One: I re-encoded the file using HandBrake and it works! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The video tag is new with HTML5, so it would be better to use the html5 tag on this question than the html tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding :

> *"@VC.One : The video you posted does work on our intranet site! `What does this mean for my mp4 file?` It was converted from .mov to .mp4 (H.264) using VLC (file->convert)."*

You did not provide any details about the input file, but likely it means your video  has an incompatible [**H264 profile**](https://superuser.com/a/489092). Encoding with a setting of profile `Baseline @ level 3.0` is best for successful playback on all systems.

**Solutions** :

**(1)** Within **Internet Explorer** options, try enabling option (tick) : *"**Use software rendering**"*. 
 This should be the simplest way to get video playback. If still problematic, try my other solutions...

[image]

**(2)** Try using a `<video>` tag setup like this :

```
<video width="100%" controls loop="true" autoplay="true">
    <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2" />
</video>
```

**(3)** Re-encode the MP4 video with acceptable *[to Internet Exlorer]* settings for H.264/MP4.

I don't convert with [**VLC**](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) but for best results :

- Make sure the input `.mov` contains...

  - video of H.264 codec (and AAC/MP3 audio, if has sound).
  - H.264 is encoded with `Baseline` **profile**.
- If input is not H.264 then **un-tick** option *"`Keep original video track`"* (it must be un-selected).

> *"@VC.One: `I re-encoded` the file using HandBrake and `it works`! Thank you very much for your help."*

You're welcome and I'm glad you got a useful suggestion.
PS: +1 for actively trying to solve issue by yourself too.

You used the [**HandBrake**](https://handbrake.fr/) solution, but for [**FFmpeg**](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) users (like me) we can try :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level:v 3.0 -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -refs:v 1 -strict -2 output.mp4
```

**Finally...**

If still any getting issues, then share a (temporary) online link to the input `.mov` file for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the loop and autoplay values should be a boolean (i.e true or false) value....

```
    <video width="100%" loop="true" autoplay="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to care about IE because it has only 4% of share in whole. You can see here https://www.w3schools.com/Browsers/default.asp
But if you want to work it on IE then you need to check video tag support in IE browser.
You can see it has no support but in IE 11 https://caniuse.com/#search=video
I don't this is properly supported so you can use modernizer for this purpose. 
Hopefully, it will help. s